# Avoiding polling on services like Heroku and Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, messaging, notifications, heroku, polling

I do not think there's a way to do this but I thought I'd ask to see what workarounds people are using to avoid polling on Heroku and/or GAE.

How are you sending out notifications in somewhat real-time from these apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE can use one of the following to notify another system:

- xmpp
- urlfetch to a callback url

  - like to pubsubhubbub
- send email

Answer (score 1):

As @dar mentions, you can use [PubSubHubbub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub) to do realtime notification without polling.  Nick Johnson has an [excellent tutorial](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/02/Consuming-RSS-feeds-with-PubSubHubbub) on using an existing PubSubHubbub server, or even including a server with your application.

This will let you publish feeds and subscribe to them in realtime without polling.

Answer (score 1):

With Heroku's new Cedar stack you can do long polling.

There's a link to some [long polling example](http://spongetech.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/long-noodle-heroku-long-polling-with-node-js-jquery-rails-cross-site/) code here.